# How is used ほか here?

Tags: usage

"新しくなったトイレの内側の壁には、フクロウなどの動物の**ほか**自動車が色鮮やかに描かれ、近くにある池袋第二保育園の園児がイメージなどを考え、区内で活動するクリエイターのグループが仕上げました。"

I don't understand because フクロウなどの動物のほか is followed by 自動車 without any link between them so I don't know how we can be certain of the meaning ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case, ほか, or rather, のほか is being used as "in addition to" or "as well as". "owls and other animals, as well as vehicles/automobiles"...  or "owls and other animals, in addition to vehicles/automobiles"

Comment: I see but what about the rules of usage ? Because when it's "のほか" it's a noun so I don't understand why we can follow it by another noun without particles  etc ?

Comment: "のほか  " is a connective phrase, used to say that two separate things should be considered together.  As such, it IS the particle. Connecting two nouns, in this case.

Comment: Ah yes, I've just found のほかに being used similarly, how to know when the に is necessary ? @ericfromabeno ?

Comment: sorry for my previous comment, if anyone was trying to follow this... I wrote it, edited it, then edited it again another 2 or 3 times... so... I'm done editing now. -_-...

Comment: のほかに is to draw attention to a verb, generally speaking. "この人数のほかに誰がきますか？　("In addition to these people, who is coming?" ...or more simply: "Who else is coming?"

Comment: `how to know when the に is necessary` 「フクロウなどの動物**のほか**自動車が色鮮やかに描かれ‥」「フクロウなどの動物**のほかに**自動車が色鮮やかに描かれて‥」この場合は、どちらでもいいような気が・・。「のほか」は、「のほかに」より文語的ですよね。